# Notification status bar text not appearing on Notification Tray, but the icon does appear

Tags: android, notifications

My app receives a Notification, the sound is heard, the little icon is shown, however the status text is not shown.

Up until Marshmallow i did not face this issue, weird..
I use the SetTicker method to set the status bar text property into the Notification.Builder object.

this is my code:

```
Notification.Builder nb = new Notification.Builder(GCMIntentService.this);

        nb.setSmallIcon(mSmallIconRes)
            .setContentTitle(mContentTitle)
            .setContentText(mContentText)
            .setStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle().bigText(mContentText))
            .setTicker(mTicker)
            .setLargeIcon(result == null ? mDefaultLargeIcon : result)
            .setSubText("")
            .setContentInfo(mContentInfo)               
            .setWhen(mWhen)
            .setSound(alarmSound);
```

Comment: Was it working in Marshmallow before setting set ticker method???

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you just want to add some text on the second line about the status try adding  `.setContentText("You're text here")`

More info can be found here

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setContentText%28java.lang.CharSequence%29

EDIT:

Apparently 'As of the L release, this text is no longer shown on screen' so that may be why you're having an issue here